# Scala pattern match repeated regex groups

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

How can I extract a list from some repeated values by regex patterns, e.g.

```
val fruits = "fruits: apple, orange, banana"
fruits match {
  case regex(fruits) => // where `fruits` is `List[String] = List(apple, orgran, banana)`
}
```

Other than

```
case regex(rawFruits) => rawFruits.split(",")
```

UPDATED:

I'm interested specially in pattern matching, since there could be multiple lists in the input string value

Comment: Please let me know if the two solutions below work for you.

Comment: I see you have visited SO after my comment above. Have you had time to check my suggestions? Please provide feedback, else, we cannot know what works for you or not.

Answer (score 2):

With pattern matching, you may only grab one match in a string. Thus, a solution will be to use the regex API directly.

**Solutoion 1: Simple two-step way**

You may grab all occurrences of `word+one or more sequences of 1+ spaces and then words` and then split the matches with the `spaces-comma-spaces` pattern:

```
val fruits = "fruits: apple, orange, banana and vegetables: carrots, potatos, cabbage"
val regex = """\w+(?:,\s*\w+)+""".r
val results = (regex findAllIn fruits).map(_ split """\s*,\s*""").toList
for (l <- results) println(l.toList)
```

Output:

```
List(apple, orange, banana)
List(carrots, potatos, cabbage)
```

See the [Scala demo](https://rextester.com/TCNJLJ26549).

**Solution 2: "one regex to rule them all"**

You may use a single regex to grab any individual word if the word is part of a comma-separated streak of words using `findAllIn`:

```
val fruits = "fruits: apple, orange, banana"
val regex = """(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|(?=\w+(?:,\s*\w+)+))(\w+)""".r
val results = (regex findAllIn fruits).matchData.map(_ group 1).toList
println(results)
// => List(apple, orange, banana)
```

See the [Scala demo](https://rextester.com/YOEC65314)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|(?=\w+(?:,\s*\w+)+))` - one of the two alternatives:

  - `\G(?!^)\s*,\s*` - end of the previous match and then a comma enclosed with optional whitespace(s)
  - `|` - or
  - `(?=\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)+)` - the location followed with 1+ word chars and then 1+ repetitions of a comma enclosed with optional whitespace(s) and then 1+ word chars
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars (letters, digits or `_`s)

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rg3kun/1).

**Pattern matching to only find a single match**

Note you may parse this string of yours using `match` block to extract this streak of comma-separated words and then split them:

```
val fruits = "fruits: apple, orange, banana."
val regex = """(\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)+)""".r.unanchored
val results = fruits match {
  case regex(m) => m.split("""\s*,\s*""").toList
  case _ => List("")
}
println(results) // => List(apple, orange, banana)
```

See [another Scala demo](https://rextester.com/TBIWNS37014).

Note:

- Here, `.unanchored` is necessary to return a partial match
- The whole pattern is wrapped with a capturing group since we need to access the found text inside the `match` block using that group
- `.split("""\s*,\s*""")` splits the found text with a comma enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- If there is no match, `case _ => List("")` will return an empty list.

Comment: Thanks, that very interesting solutions. But the first is not quite pattern matching, and the other was mentioned in the original question. Do you know how to pattern match this? e.g. for the case there could be multiple list in the string value

Comment: @ntviet18 The first one is the *solution*. It does not have to look like that, you may grab the match of `\w+(?:\s+\w+)+` and then split with `\s*,\s*`, same as in the second solution. It will be more readable. You can't use pattern matching to get multiple matches.

Comment: @ntviet18 Added more to the answer.